Raw Tx to structure
Is it possible to extract the raw data from etherscan and then trying to decode it into readable format?
Specifically, i would like to sign transactions using python and i have always relied on rabby wallet generating the structure for me. But in cases where Rabby is not available and only metamask is, i am unable to find out what value goes inti “data”.
transaction = {
    'to': '0xF0109fC8DF283027b6285cc889F5aA624EaC1F55',
    'value': 1000000000,
    'gas': 2000000,
    'gasPrice': 234567897654321,
    'nonce': 0,
    'chainId': 1
}

Above shows the method which i would like to use. I know every field except Value.
Given the transaction on etherscan, is there a way i could find out what goes into value?

I've edited my answer with info related to Arbitrum Sepolia that you've asked. Please check. And kindly accept the answer if it solves your problem. Thanks.

You can achieve that by accessing eth_getTransactionByHash action using Etherscan API after getting the Etherscan API key.
Here's the minimal code in Python:
import requests
from web3 import Web3

def get_transaction_data(tx_hash, etherscan_api_key):
    url = f"https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionByHash&txhash={tx_hash}&apikey={etherscan_api_key}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    if data:
        return data["result"]
    else:
        raise Exception("Error fetching data from Etherscan")


# Example usage
etherscan_api_key = "YOUR_ETHERSCAN_API_KEY"
tx_hash = "YOUR_TRANSACTION_HASH"

transaction_data = get_transaction_data(tx_hash, etherscan_api_key)
# print(transaction_data)

transaction = {
    'to': transaction_data['to'],
    'data': transaction_data['input'],
    'value': Web3.to_int(hexstr=transaction_data['value']),
    'gas': Web3.to_int(hexstr=transaction_data['gas']),
    'gasPrice': Web3.to_int(hexstr=transaction_data['gasPrice']),
    'nonce': Web3.to_int(hexstr=transaction_data['nonce']),
    'chainId': Web3.to_int(hexstr=transaction_data['chainId']),
}

print(transaction)


For a network other than Ethereum L1, you need to create account and get API key from the corresponding explorer like in case of Arbitrum, it should be created on Arbiscan.
For Arbitrum Mainnet, the endpoint should be https://api.arbiscan.io/api.
And, for Arbitum Sepolia, it should be https://api-sepolia.arbiscan.io/api.
You can get all of this info from the corresponding explorer's API  documentation, like for Arbiscan, it's mentioned here.
Then, you just have to use the corresponding endpoint in the url value used in the get_transaction_data function:
def get_transaction_data(tx_hash, explorer_api_key):
    url = f"https://api-sepolia.arbiscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionByHash&txhash={tx_hash}&apikey={explorer_api_key}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    if data:
        return data["result"]
    else:
        raise Exception("Error fetching data from Etherscan")


Hello syed i am so sorry i am unable to make a comment due to lack of reputation, i will delete this after you read it. I would like to ask, what if my transaction contains more fields that what i have specified? For example, the program returned {'to': '0x5ff137d4b0fdcd49dca30c7cf57e578a026d2789', 'value': 0, 'gas': 79890305, 'gasPrice': 210000000, 'nonce': 53268, 'chainId': 421614}
but i am quite sure that there should be a data field. My question would be, is it then possible to see what are the required fields i need in order for me to successfully use w3.eth.account.sign_transaction()

@TanJun, I'd already added the data field in my answer. You can get that using the input key i.e., transaction_data['input'].
